# How to optimize cell size for plt.matshow

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to display a matrix with values using `matshow` using the following code:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
vander = np.vander(x_values, N=3)

ax.matshow(vander, cmap="Blues")
for i in range(3):
    for j in range(10):
        c = vander[j, i]
        ax.text(i, j, str(c), va='center', ha='center')


plt.show()
```

The problem I get is that when I set values for each cell is that matrix values overlap as it only has 3 columns looking like this:

I'm not sure how to make cells wide enough as I set text after the matrix is plotted
[image]

Comment: Please provide a runnable code with data to reproduce the figure.

Comment: Try: `fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(3,20))`